# Run .sh file to set directory permissions from Chef in OpsWorks

Tags: bash, shell, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

In deploying a website with a CMS to an AWS OpsWorks instance, I need to set the correct permissions on upload directories and such. To allow for easier customization of these tasks I would like my custom chef recipe to simply run a .sh file reciding in the root of the deployed app instead of having to create separate recipes or use custom chef json.

When I run this, the bash "deploy" task seems to run fine, but the commands from the .sh file have no effect.  In this case I'm deploying a site with Craft CMS.

Here is my chef recipe:

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  bash "deploy" do
    deploy_script = "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/deploy.sh"
    code "sh #{deploy_script}"
  end
end
```

And here is the .sh file:

```
sudo su
chmod 774 craft/app/
chmod 774 craft/config/
chmod 774 craft/storage/
touch craft/test.txt
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those paths are relative.  Mostly likely you need to set the `cwd` of your bash resource.

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  bash "deploy" do
    deploy_script = "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/deploy.sh"
    code "sh #{deploy_script}"
    cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
  end
end
```